# Is there any process to make all the folder structure automatically when i develop wordpress theme.?

Tags: wordpress

Is there any process to make all the folder structure 
automatically when I develop wordpress theme?

Comment: Write a simple script? if(!is_dir($folder1){mkdir($folder1);} etc.

Comment: Please see my answer below. I believe this is what you're after.

Answer (score 0):

Just write a script to do it, something like this.

You could replace the hard-coded theme name with a $_GET parameter so you can easily use the tool each time you start out creating a new template.

```
<?php

$theme_name = $_GET['name'];
$base_path = "/wordpress/themes/";
$paths = array(
    "{$base_path}{$theme_name}/js",
    "{$base_path}{$theme_name}/css",
    "{$base_path}{$theme_name}/images",
    "{$base_path}{$theme_name}/inc"
);

foreach($paths as $path){
    if(!is_dir($path)){
        mkdir($path);
    }
}
```

Call it dir_maker.php and hit dir_maker.php?name=awesome_theme in a browser or terminal.